# WPF Line positioning within Grid columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, line

I have a `Grid` with 3 equally sized columns.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I want to draw a horizontal line so that it would start from the middle of the first column and end at the middle of the last column.

```
<Line Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" 
      X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0"
      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

The desired result should be the line shown in the bottom part of the below picture.

[image]

Hardcoding `Margins` to `Line` won't probably work here.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

Create a nested Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Line Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Fill" X2="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the "best" way... but what if you used a border instead of a line?  Then just set the background using a color/transparent gradient with hard stops at the 1/6 and 5/6 points?

Alternatively, you could use 6 equally spaced columns and colspan it 4 from the 2nd column.  That would have implications on the other items in the grid, though.

```
<Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0" Height="5">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1666"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent"  Offset="0.8334"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.1667"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.8333"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
```